# External Ajax: All at Once, As Needed, or Something Else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created a Magic The Gathering site for my friends and I to use.  On this site, we upload our decks of cards, and on the page where you can view all the cards in the deck each card is a link to the card on `http://gatherer.wizards.com/`.  For ease of use, though, I made it so that when you hover over any of the card names, the card image gets Ajax'd in from gatherer, thus letting you see the card without having to click the link.

The question is: should I load all of the ~40 or so card images all at once when the page loads, or should I continuously load the images as they are hovered over, or is there some other way I should be doing it?

As it stands, I load each card as it is hovered over.  My concern is that, as people mouse up and down the list, that is a LOT of requests to Gatherer.  It would probably save requests to load them all up at the start, but I'm not sure if Gatherer would be upset with me for a sudden flurry of requests every time someone loads one of the decks on my site.

A solution I thought of was to load cards as they are hovered over, but save the image in a hidden container and just reload it when they mouse over it AGAIN.  Thus if they load the page and don't look at anything, no needless requests were sent, but if they stay on the page for 30 minutes looking at every card over and over again, we don't inundate Gatherer with requests.

I just don't know if the method I'm using is wasteful - from a bandwidth standpoint for me or for gatherer, or from any other standpoint that I'm not familiar with.  Are there any golden rules of external Ajax that I should know, for instance?

The method I'm currently using, which I assume is probably the worst implementation possible, but it was a proof of concept:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var container = $('#cardImageHolder');
  $('.bumpin a').mouseenter(function(){
    doAjax($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
  });

  function doAjax(url){
    // if it is an external URI
    if(url.match('^http')){
      // call YQL
      $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
                "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
                encodeURIComponent(url)+
                "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
        // this function gets the data from the successful 
        // JSON-P call
        function(data){
          // if there is data, filter it and render it out
          if(data.results[0]){
            var data = filterData(data.results[0]);
            var src = $(data).find('.leftCol img').first().attr('src');
            var fixedImageSrc = src.replace("../../", "http://gatherer.wizards.com/");
            var image = $(data).find('.leftCol img').first().attr('src', fixedImageSrc);
            container.html(image);
          // otherwise tell the world that something went wrong
          } else {
            var errormsg = "<p>Error: can't load the page.</p>";
            container.html(errormsg);
          }
        }
      );
    // if it is not an external URI, use Ajax load()
    } else {
      $('#target').load(url);
    }
  }
  // filter out some nasties
  function filterData(data){
    data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g,'');
    data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g,'');
    data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g,'');
    data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g,'');
    data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g,'');
    data = data.replace(/<script.*\/>/,'');
    return data;
  }
});
```

Comment: So, let me get this straight. You're stealing copyrighted material from someone else's site, and you want our help in doing it efficiently? Hmmm....

Comment: Not at all, wizards allows the use of its card scans for site's like mine.  We aren't playing the game on the site, we just want to be able to see each other's decklists from the tournament site so it feels more "official" and not just like casual kitchen table play.  Plenty of sites draw card images from gatherer - it is the official repository of all Magic Cards.

Comment: Ok, then you should be polite and at least cache the cards when you've retrieved each one. Perhaps even store them in a browser database so that you reduce the calls even further. Both approaches are compatible and will also increase the performance of your app.

Comment: You mean cache them even beyond the page, so that when ANOTHER user comes to the page, I first check my cache for that card image, and if I don't already have it THEN I request from gatherer?

Comment: Cache them on the page, by downloading the image if you don't already have it, then simply hiding the img tag when it's not visible and toggling the hidden status when it is. Beyond that you can store the image in the browser's database, so that when the same user comes back the images that have been previously downloaded can be retrieved locally without hitting the wizard's site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no Golden Rules of Ajax. Loading 40 images up front would minimize load time upon hover, but would greatly increase how much bandwidth is used when the page is first loaded.

You will always have these types of balance questions. It's up to *you* to decide what is best, and tweak it based on empirical data.

> "A solution I thought of was to load cards as they are hovered over,
>   but save the image in a hidden container and just reload it when they
>   mouse over it AGAIN. Thus if they load the page and don't look at
>   anything, no needless requests were sent, but if they stay on the page
>   for 30 minutes looking at every card over and over again, we don't
>   inundate Gatherer with requests."

This sounds reasonable.

If I were you, though, I would load every picture when the user first loads the page. Let the browser cache the images and you don't have to worry about it. Plus, this is likely the easiest method. Don't over complicate things when you don't have to :)

Comment: So how do I let the browser use the cached image instead of automatically retrieving from Gatherer?  The function, as it stands, doesn't know whether the browser has this image cached, so the `mouseenter()` event fires EVERY time they mouse over?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question fully. Can you write a crawler to store the images on your local server?

Comment: I never have done anything like that before, but I see no reason why I couldn't learn.  I can probably cache every card image the first time it gets downloaded into my database (It's a django site so that should be easy, I assume).  Then I can just check my database before I request to gatherer.

Comment: Sure, writing a crawler is fairly straight forward. The broad idea is to download every card to your server, and stop using gatherer.wizards.com/ as the source.